# Html.Display does not work with ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.textbox

Html.Display does not work with ViewBag.

```
@Html.Display("disp", (string)@ViewBag.disp)
```

I must use this viewbag because it can be modified by a search button selecting another disp.

```
@Html.TextBox("disp", (string)@ViewBag.disp)
```

If I use TextBox instead of Display it works, but I want to be read-only. How it is possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because there's no overload of Display which takes a value as argument.

So.

You can simply do

```
@ViewBag.disp
```

or (if it contains HTMl)

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.disp)
```

or if you want a TextBox

```
@Html.TextBox("disp", (string)@ViewBag.disp, new{@readonly = true})
```